# Integrate webrtc media in pjsip

Tags: webrtc, pjsip, pjsua2

I am trying to integrate webrtc media in pjsip. Can someone help me to do this? I am able to create webrtc sdp but pjsip is giving error

pjsua_media.c  .Call 1: initializing media..
pjsua_call.c  . Error initializing media channel: Not Acceptable Here [status=170488]
pjsua_media.c  .Call 1: deinitializing media..

Comment: opposite party also need to support webrtc media. does it support?

Comment: I am making an application. so both ends support webrtc